# Как сделать поиск с помощью Flask

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

Нужно написать приложение по управлению электронной библиотекой: поиск книг по названию либо автору.

Может кто-то встречал. Где можно прочитать или посмотреть или кто-то делал что-то подобное?

Comment: В качестве ORM что используете?

Comment: SQLAlchemy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flask -- это микро- веб-фреймворк, поэтому она имеет отношение к поиску только в той степени, что она позволяет использовать различные ORM (нет жёсткой привязки к какому-то одному решению).

Если вопрос: как реализовать поиск с помощью Flask-SQLAlchemy, то чтобы отобразить книгу, указанную по автору и названию в ссылке, можно написать:

```
@app.route('/book/<author>/<title>')
def show_book(author, title):
    book = Book.query.filter_by(author=author, title=title).first_or_404()
    return render_template('show_book.html', book=book)
```

где Book это SQLAlchemy модель, которая превращает этот код в запрос к базе данных.

См. другие примеры в руководстве пользователя: [Querying Records](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/queries.html#querying-records).

Вот минимальное полное Flask-SQLAlchemy приложение с поиском книг (`book_app.py`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from flask import Flask, render_template # $ pip install flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy # $ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/test.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Book(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String(120))
    title = db.Column(db.String(200))

    def __init__(self, author, title):
        self.author = author
        self.title = title
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Book %r: %r>' % (self.author, self.title)

@app.cli.command('createdb') # команда по созданию базы данных для примера
def createdb_command():
    """Create dummy database."""
    db.create_all()
    db.session.add(Book('J.C. McCrae', 'Worm'))
    db.session.commit()

@app.route('/book/<author>/<title>')
def show_book(author, title):
    book = Book.query.filter_by(author=author, title=title).first_or_404()
    return render_template('show_book.html', book=book)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

И соответствующий шаблон `templates/show_book.html`:

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>{{ book.title }} :: {{ book.author }}</title>
<body>
<dl>
 <dt> Автор
 <dd> {{ book.author }}
 <dt> Название
 <dd> {{ book.title }}
</dl>
```

Чтобы попробовать приложение:

- установить зависимости:

  ```
  $ pip install Flask-SQLAlchemy
  ```
- создать базу данных:

  ```
  $ flask --app=book_app createdb
  ```
- запустить приложение:

  ```
  $ flask --app=book_app run
  ```
- открыть ссылку:

  ```
  $ python -mwebbrowser http://localhost:5000/book/J.C.%20McCrae/Worm
  ```

Если команда `flask` не найдена, то нужно обновиться до текущей версии в разработке:

```
$ pip install -U git+https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask
```

Чтобы можно было искать книгу либо названию либо по автору, например используя: `http://localhost:5000/search?author=<author>&title=<title>`, где параметры не обязательны, можно добавить:

```
@app.route('/search')
def search_book():
    params = {name: request.args.get(name) for name in ['author', 'title']}
    params = {k: v for k, v in params.items() if v} # отфильтровываем пустые параметры
    book = Book.query.filter_by(**params).first_or_404()
    return render_template('show_book.html', book=book)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ваш ответ правильный, но я имел ввиду полною реализацию такой апликухи, используя: 
● Flask
● SQLAlchemy (Declarative)
● SQLite (встроенный в приложение)
● Jinja2 Templates
● WTForms

Хотелось бы почитать об создании апликух с помощью Flaska. Читал на хабре статью Мега-Учебник Flask. Если знаете что то подходящее дайте ссылочку или автора(желательно на русском), заранее благодарен)

Comment: @arcs_host: я добавил полный пример.

Comment: Спасибо, а как вы изучали, по документации?

Comment: @arcs_host: Я добавил пример как искать только по одному критерию. "как изучал?": посмотрел "hello world" пример во введении, скопировал -- заработал, поправил для своих нужд. Если параметры не знаю для функции -- смотрю в документации. Если не ясно, как что-то сделать -- гуглю пример. Чтобы плохой код не копировать, необходимо некоторую базу иметь (представлять как хороший результат может выглядеть, отсеивать небезопасный код, итд).

Comment: Спасибо, попробую такой же метод.