# Как сделать эту функцию более короткой не теряя функционала?

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

```
def addToDb(list):
    if type(list[0]) == str:
        if type(list[1]) == str:
            if type(list[2]) == str:
                if type(list[3]) == int:
                    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO clients VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)""", (list[0], list[1], list[2], list[3]))
                    conn.commit()
                    print('Выполнена запись в базу данных')
                else:
                    print('Аргумент number не является Int ')
            else:
                print('Аргумент time не является Str')
        else:
            print('Аргумент ip не является Str')
    else:
        print('Аргумент status не является Str')
```

Comment: Осваиваю питон, не хотелось бы 'быдлокодить' начинать :)

Comment: Незачем делать много вложенных ифов. Проверяйте переменные по одной и если они некорректны — пишите в лог причину и прерывайте выполнение (с помощью выброса исключения, `return` или `exit(1)`.

Comment: Подумайте также, а здесь ли нужно проверять тип данных. Возможно, ошибку можно заметить раньше, там где вы их получаете. Там с этим можно будет сделать что-то конструктивное, например переспросить ввод из консоли, переотправить запрос и т.п.

Comment: Другими словами, пересчитывайте сдачу, не отходя от кассы ))

Comment: И ещё накину: `print` стоит использовать только в CLI-приложениях. То есть, когда человек только что ввел какие-то данные и будет читать ответ. Если это серверное приложение, то используйте нормальное логирование. https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/logging.html

Comment: это я знаю. тут больше для понимания самого процесса были принты сделаны.

Comment: По стилю кода: **никогда** не используйте названия типов (`list`, `str` и т.д.) в качестве имен переменных.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
In [101]: lst = ['a','b','c',1]
```

проверка на "строки" первых трех элементов:

```
In [104]: all(isinstance(x, str) for x in lst[:3])
Out[104]: True
```

проверка четвертого элемента на "int":

```
In [105]: isinstance(lst[3], int)
Out[105]: True
```

**Немного улучшенный ответ:**

```
In [135]: lst = [1,'b',2,'x']

In [136]: chk_type = (
     ...:   ['status', str],
     ...:   ['ip', str],
     ...:   ['time', str],
     ...:   ['number', int]
     ...: )
     ...:

In [137]: for i,x in enumerate(chk_type):
     ...:     if not isinstance(lst[i], x[1]):
     ...:         print('parameter [{}] has wrong type (should be [{}])!'.format(x[0], x[1].__name__))
     ...:
parameter [status] has wrong type (should be [str])!
parameter [time] has wrong type (should be [str])!
parameter [number] has wrong type (should be [int])!
```

Comment: Круто, но потерялись сообщения о том, где конкретно ошибка.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да, действительно, спасибо! Сейчас попробую исправить...

Comment: Мне кажется, надо сначала у автора выяснить контекст. Я вот не уверен, что там будет кому читать эти сообщения. А если будет — то что проверку нужно делать не сразу при получении, а только перед записью в базу.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, да по поводу проверки "не отходя от кассы" - я полностью согласен. Проверять лучше сразу при вводе/получении значения...

Comment: Да эта функция будет вызываться сервером  при получении данных от клиента. принты для меня чтоб меньше ошибок делать.

Comment: Всем спасибо!!!

Comment: @MaxU плюсанул сразу. Новый вариант тоже хорош.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, спасибо, но я не из-за плюса - не хотелось оставлять вопрос неотвеченным ;)

Answer (score 6):

Явную проверку типов во время исполнения редко в Питоне нужно делать. Как правило это указывает на ошибку в дизайне кода.

Как валидировать входные данные зависит от задачи.  По известным спискам значений (whitelisting), схеме. К примеру, [cerberus](http://docs.python-cerberus.org/en/stable/).

Часто можно упростить код до:

```
def add_to_db(*args):
    with conn:
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO clients VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", args)
```

Если не произойдёт исключения, то  происходит commit.

Для проверки типов аргументов,  можно использовать аннотации типов, читаемые статическим анализатором типа mypy и/или декоратор, чтобы во время исполнения аргументы валидировать (не тестировано):

```
from typing import NamedTuple
import enforce  # $ pip install enforce

class Client(NamedTuple):
    status : str
    ip : str
    time : str
    number : int 

@enforce.runtime_validation
def add_client(client : Client) -> None:
    with conn:
        conn.execute("INSERT INTO clients VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)", client)
```

Связанный вопрос: [How to use Python decorators to check function arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15299878/4279)

Если вы такой код часто пишите, то попробуйте ORM. Вот  [пример кода для SQLAlchemy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/372177/23044):

```
my_client = MyClient(status, ip, time, number)
session.add(my_client)
session.commit()
```

SQLAlchemy по умолчанию опирается на базу данных как на самый эффективный и надёжный источник о корректности данных, но вы можете и свои проверки добавить [How can I verify Column data types in the SQLAlchemy ORM?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8980735/4279)