# Flask приложение зависает на открытии базы данных

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Иногда моё Flask приложение зависает на следующей строке:

```
with shelve.open('user_db') as db:
```

(это происходит случайно)
Весь код приложения привести не могу (очень большой), но в общем это выглядит так:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def mpage():
    Обработка запроса
    Запуск следующего метода (set_timer) в потоке
    Возвращение кода 200

def set_timer():
    Запускается таймер, запускается отдельный процесс (см следующий метод) и проверяется время выполнения этого процесса

def seps():
    Тут почти в самом начале лежит проблемная строка
```

Приложение зависает именно на этой строке, я это выяснил путём отладочных сообщений. Кто-нибудь может подсказать, в чём проблема?

UPD: заменил shelve на sqlite3. Открываю ее в глобальную переменную так:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('user_db.db', check_same_thread=False)
```

Зависает здесь:

```
db = conn.cursor()
user_mode = db.execute('SELECT id, mode FROM users WHERE id={}'.format(user_id)).fetchall()
```

Не могу понять в чём проблема теперь

upd2:
Полностью перешёл на flask_sqlalchemy. Ошибка не пропала. Код:
Модель базы:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///./user.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    mode = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=False)
```

Как пользуюсь:

```
report += 'Открытие БД\n'
    t_user = User.query.get(user_id)
    if not t_user:
        user = User(id=user_id, mode=0)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        t_user = User.query.get(user_id)
    user_mode = t_user.mode
```

И где-то в этих строках зависает. Что делать - не знаю

Comment: Стактрэйс хотя бы привели..

Comment: @Xyanight стактрейс привести не могу, т.к всё это происходит в многопоточном/процессорном приложении. А так, никакой ошибки нет. Код просто зависает там, а потом всё это вырубается в методе set_timer()

Comment: shelve не поддерживает параллельный доступ. Попробуйте синхронизировать доступ  или используйте решения, которые поддерживают параллельный доступ. Какое решение выбрать, зависит какую роль у вас shelve выполняет.

Comment: @jfs В shelve у меня база типа пользователь:цифра (номер режима). Какое решение мне лучше использовать тут?

Comment: @vladF если особых предпочтений нет, то любая база данных подойдёт. [Пример с поиском книг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/372177/23044)

Comment: @jfs Я пробую использовать SQLite, но у меня опять проблема. Не могли бы Вы помочь? Я дописал тему

Comment: @vladF я вам дал ссылку на полный пример кода. Не изобретайте велосипед(что как вы убедились к ошибкам ведёт), используйте его как основу.

Comment: @jfs Знаю, что прошло уже много времени, но проблема осталась. Обновил сообщение еще раз. Уже перерыл много информации, но не могу исправить сам

Comment: @vladF, проверьте условие `if not t_user:` - там должен быть либо Юзер, либо `None`. А на `None` следует проверять оператором `is` / `is not`

Comment: @prusanov Я проверю, но сомневаюсь в этой догадке. Приложение зависает не всегда, вне зависимости от этого условия

Comment: Попробуйте расставить банальные print'ы по шагам, чтобы в многопоточном режиме отследить, какой шаг выполнился, какой - нет.

Comment: @prusanov Так я именно так и понял, что зависание на этой строке

Comment: Не пробовали создавать отдельный connect в каждом потоке? И, кажется, в тему: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22739590/how-to-share-single-sqlite-connection-in-multi-threaded-python-application , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739342/sqlite-sharing-connections-across-threads-to-read-and-write

Comment: Дополнительно - задайте параметр `app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True`, должно многое проясниться.

Comment: @prusanov Пробовал, но никаких изменений не увидел, в консоль ничего не выводится дополнительно

Comment: Зависание происходит, потому что SQLite база блокируется в одном из параллельных потоков, а другие не могут получить к ней доступ (проблема аналогична использованию `shelve`). Может попробовать перейти к архитектуре "производитель-потребитель", где только один из них будет иметь подключение к БД, а пользователи будут добавляться через Queue?

Comment: есть ли у вас минимальный пример кода, который проблему демонстрирует (можно запустить)? [mcve] Можно не минимальный, но тогда, чтобы настройка сводилась к паре docker-compose команд.

Answer (score 4):

Просто обрывается коннект к базе. Добавьте такие строки в ваш конфиг и будет счастье:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_RECYCLE'] = 299
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_TIMEOUT'] = 20
```

Comment: Не работает. Код добавил в главный файл приложения, но оно всё равно зависает на этой точке

Comment: @vladF попробуйте использовать дебаг `import pdb` и в нужном месте `pdb.set_trace()`

Answer (score 2):

Возможно мой совет будет полезен - попробуйте `Postgresql` Вот пример кода:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String, create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, scoped_session
from contextlib import contextmanager

Base = declarative_base()
engine = create_engine('postgresql://user:pass@localhost:5432/db_name',
                       pool_size=50,
                       max_overflow=0,
                       echo=True)


@contextmanager
def session():
    connection = engine.connect()
    db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=True, bind=engine))
    try:
        yield db_session
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        db_session.remove()
        connection.close()


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sign'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50))

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name


def new_user(name):
    with session() as s:
        user = User(name)
        s.add(user)
        s.commit()
        return s.id
```

Comment: Я решил свою проблему переходом на эту ДБ, но у меня получилось сделать это только костылём - просто проверял, зависает на этом месте код или нет